# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' fix?

Tags: python

```py
def separate (gpsTrackPoints,gpsTrackPointsReorg):
    trackPoints = open (gpsTrackPoints,"r")
    trackPointsReorg = open (gpsTrackPointsReorg,"w")
    trackPoints.readline()
    lines = trackPoints.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split(",")
        pointID = parts[0]
        long = parts[1]
        lat = parts[2]
        alt = parts[3]
        dateTime = parts[4]
        dateTimeSplit = line.split("-")
        dateStr = dateTimeSplit[0]
        timeStr = dateTimeSplit[1]
        reOrg = ("pointID:{}, longitude:{}, latitude:{}, altitude:{}, date:{}, time:{}".format(pointID,long,lat,alt,dateStr,timeStr))
        #reOrg = (pointID + "," + long + "," + lat + "," + "alt" + "," + "date" + "," + "time")
        gpsTrackPointsReorg.write(reOrg)
    trackPoints.close()
    trackPointsReorg.close()
    
separate("C:/Users/trwil/SpatProg/HW3/Data/GPS_trackpoints.txt","C:/Users/trwil/SpatProg/HW3/Data/GPS_trackpointsReorg.txt")
```

This is my code but I just get an error on the `gpsTrackPoints.write(reOrg)` line saying `str has no attribute write`.
How do I fix this?

I don't know what else to input there.

Comment: Did you mean to write: `trackPointsReorg.write(reOrg)`? The function already opens that file for writing for you.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that fixed it. I needed someone else's eyes to see my little error.

Comment: For future reference, the first place to look for an error *is* the line that python points to. (And, yes, there have been plenty of questions on stackoverflow where the OP *insists* that there is something wrong at the indicated line, but in fact, the error is somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

You should write to `trackPointsReorg`, not `gpsTrackPointsReorg`, which is the string.